# Cannot begin writing simple "Hello world" with Ruby on cmder

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, directory, cmder

I started using Ruby for the first time after trying Python for a while. I tried starting a simple "Hello World" but kept getting this error:

```
C:\app λ ruby hello1.rb
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   ruby: No such file or directory -- hello1.rb (LoadError)
```

I'm using Visual Studio code v1.42 for my text editor and Cmder v1.3.14 for my terminal. Running ruby

2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x64-mingw32].

On VSC I named my file hello1 and proceeded to write ruby hello1.rb on Cmder to run the program on it as I was instructed but this error always pops up no matter what. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: According to the prompt, you’re in `C:\app` – chances are that your `hello1.rb` is located somewhere else. Either `cd` into the correct directory or pass the file’s full path.

Comment: Close the question by accepting any answer so that people will stop answering if you have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Installation path

   Ensure to check
   environment variables whether the Path value is set to Ruby
   installation. Try reinstalling once again if couldn't resolve path.
2. Same directory

   Make sure you're running it from the same directory the file is in. Ensure by "ls" cmd
3. Command error

   It can happen for anyone. Remove extra white spaces if made.

Happy coding in Ruby!